# VB6 Packaging and Organization

Tags: vb6, package

Is there any clean way to package VB6 Class Modules, other than writing DLLs or manually adding prefixes to the module names?

EDIT: I'm hoping VB6 has something along the lines of packages or namespaces from other languages.

Comment: You mean with an EXE or separately?  Do you mean for purposes of deployment, or for clarity in the development environment?

Comment: Sorry, I meant for development, like packages or namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Splitting functionality into separate DLLs is as close as you can get to packages, and [it's a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505883/how-do-you-unit-test-an-exe-with-3rd-party-dll/507053#507053). I believe if you [use registry-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345111/how-can-you-force-vb6-to-use-the-dlls-and-ocxs-from-the-app-directory), then you don't even need to register the DLLs when you install them.

Comment: The DLL approach looks like it should do the trick, if they can be used without registration. Thanks!