# Unit Testing in VB 6 with SimplyVBUnit

Tags: unit-testing, vb6, simplyvbunit

I've recently decided to start using some light unit testing to see if it adds any value to our project, but I'm having trouble finding documentation for [SimplyVBUnit](http://simplyvbunit.sourceforge.net/).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded the binary installer for SimplyVBUnit it comes with a couple of example projects in the installation folder. Both the source code zip file and binary installer include a Help.chm showing many of the classes and how to apply them in your tests.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if anyone had created docs for it.  I did view the help, and that was helpful (no pun intended) to some degree.  And, since you're the author and you advised to review the help, it seems that the answer is no:  there is not any additional documentation other than the included example projects and compiled help file.

Comment: What kind of documentation are you looking for? Is it specific to SimplyVBUnit or more about unit testing in general?

Answer (score 3):

There's some discussion of VB6 unit testing in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6), with Gutzofter's [mini tutorial on SimplyVBUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6/468225#468225).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered collecting [test coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)?  This determines what part of your code has run, often as exercised by your unit tests.   To do this, you need a test coverage data collection tool, as well as your tests.

EDIT:  The only VB6 test coverage tool I know is http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html
Aivisto seems to have a generally good reputation for thier VB tools.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a software testing methodology that you're recommending, when I was asking about a specific unit testing framework.   That said, I'm specifically looking for automated tools to add value at little expense to our QA side.  Could you suggest a good vb 6 code automated coverage tool?

Comment: You were looking for something that adds value.  Unit tests are good.  IMHO, test coverage is an enormous value add, because it tells if your tests (unit, integration, system, interactive) are doing you any serious amount of good.    Thanks for the ding :-(

Comment: I'll cancel out that ding fer ya!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @IraBaxter i'm surprised to see this comment from someone with 49k rep! My comment is an automatically generated one after reviewing the flagged posts queue, reported by someone else.

Comment: @Neeku: Don't assume that everybody at SO, or even all high rep users, agrees with all of SO policies or the zealousness with which some people enforce them.  And this particular complaint really seemed unwarranted.  I'm not interested in discussion; I fixed it as much as practical.

Comment: @neeku Ira is in the right this time, as I think you'll see if you read the edited answer carefully. Automatic moderation tools are good servants but poor masters.