# Visual Basic 6 and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good TDD tools or resources for VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6)

I have been tasked with creating some upgrades for a older VB6 application.
Are there any unit testing solutions that VB6 could easily implement?

I honestly haven't looked at any VB6 since 1999!

Answer (score 7):

How about [SimplyVBUnit](http://simplyvbunit.sourceforge.net/)?

[Unit Testing in VB 6 with SimplyVBUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556025/unit-testing-in-vb-6-with-simplyvbunit)
MiniTutorial: [Are there any good TDD tools or resources for VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6/468225#468225)

Comment: Very nice. That looks promising. Thank you very much!

Comment: This response will be the best. SimplyVBUnit is the way to go.