# What differences are there between the frameworks that exist for unit testing vb6?

Tags: unit-testing, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good TDD tools or resources for VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6)

For my sins in a previous life I am currently faced with having to modify some legacy VB6 COM+ code.

The client absolutely does not want us to upgrade this code to .NET so that is not an option in this case.

I am uncomfortable touching this code without adding unit tests to it, but while I am experienced in using tools in the XUnit family and in the practices of TDD, I have never worked in VB6 since learning these skills, so unit testing VB6 is completely new to me.

I see that there is a product called [SimplyVBUnit](http://simplyvbunit.sourceforge.net/), as well as [VBUnit](http://www.vbunit.com/), but the online documentation for them seems limited. Has anyone used either of these tools? What are the main differences between them? Is there another tool that I should be considering?

Comment: Very similar to this question, have youy looked at the answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6

Comment: Thanks Mark - I searched for questions marked unit testing & vb6 and this one didn't show up - I'll retag it and take a look at the answers.

Comment: Having read that question, I'm voting to close mine as a duplicate. It covers pretty much the same ground and has some good information to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still open (and showing as unanswered).

As well as the previously mentioned SO question, [Are there any good TDD tools or resources for VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6), there are a couple of others.

VB Lite Unit:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/vb-lite-unit/

VbUnit2:  http://code.google.com/p/vbunit2/

Comment: The reason my question is still open is that although I voted to close it, I don't have enough reputation to close it unilaterally and it didn't garner any other close votes. However, thanks and +1 for the updated answer!