# Problem using SimplyVBUnit

Tags: unit-testing, vb6

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on where I need to put the SimplyVBUnit.dll and SimplyVBUnitUI.ocx files so I can run the tutorial in this question: [Gutzofter's mini tutorial on SimplyVBUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467789/are-there-any-good-tdd-tools-or-resources-for-vb6/468225#468225).
Where exactly do I need to reference or register these files so I can create unit tests with VB6?

When I open the source above it says it cannot load SimplyVBUnitUI.ocx and  I get the following error in the associated log file:

```
Line 13: Class SimplyVBUnitUI.SimplyVBUnitCtl of control SimplyVBUnitCtl1 was not a loaded control class.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add the ocx manually, you need to add it to the toolbox then put an instance of the UI control on a form. You will also need a reference to the dll which has the framework. Then make the form the startup object. If you installed SimplyVBUnit using an installer, there is a form in the Projects template folder (frmSimplyVBUnitRunner I think). You can copy that to the Forms templates and just add a new form (the runner form) to the project that will contain your tests.

Comment: Is there a place I can find the installer for version 3.0?

Comment: You can find it on source forge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplyvbunit/. You'll have to dig through the File menu to find it. If you download the source code version, there is a GUI Project folder that has the form (and new project) as well.

Comment: The installer worked fine. I just don't know why it won't allow me to compile it from source.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered them?

Use Start-Run and run `regsvr32 <full-path-to-file>`. Repeat this for the OCX and the DLL

Comment: Yes, I have registered both files.